# Spring Boot with Kotlin - @Value annotation not working as expected

Tags: spring, spring-boot, properties, kotlin

I'm developing a Spring boot application using Kotlin. Since I need to connect to an external API (cloudinary) I decided to add to my app a configuration class in order to store (and hide from VCS) my sensible data like username, passwords or API keys.

So this is what i did:

I created a Config class:

```
package demons

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource

@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
class AppConfig {
    @Value("\${test.prop}")
    val testProperty: String? = null
}
```

Then I added a test.prop entry in my application.properties file

```
test.prop=TEST
```

However, in every test I run, after creating an instance of AppConfig, his testProperty attribute is `null` instead of being the string `TEST`.

For instance this snippet:

```
val config = AppConfig()
System.out.println(config.testProperty)
```

would print out:

```
null
```

I've also tried using a separate .properties file instead of the default one like `myproperties.properties` and declaring the variable as `lateinit var`. In this last case the variable seems to never be initialized:

```
kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property testProperty has not been initialized
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The issue is that you are creating the instance of `AppConfig` yourself via the constructor:

> ```
> val config = AppConfig()
> ```

While this class might have Spring annotations, it is NOT spring managed if you create the instance yourself.

I recommend you borrow from the [link you mentioned in my other](https://spring.io/blog/2016/02/15/developing-spring-boot-applications-with-kotlin#property-placeholders) answer.  There are good examples of using SpringBoot to create a Spring application for you.  Below I created a 'merged' example of your test + an example from the link.  There is no need to specify a properties file, as `application.properties` is used as a property source by default.

```
@SpringBootApplication
class AppConfig {
    @Value("\${test.prop}")
    val testProperty: String? = null
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val appContext = SpringApplication.run(AppConfig::class.java, *args)
    val config = appContext.getBean(AppConfig::class.java)
    System.out.println(config.testProperty)
}
```